# What is a good practice to check if an environment variable exists or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement, environment-variables

I want to check my environment for the existence of a variable, say `"FOO"`, in Python. For this purpose, I am using the `os` standard library. After reading the library's documentation, I have figured out 2 ways to achieve my goal:

Method 1:

```
if "FOO" in os.environ:
    pass
```

Method 2:

```
if os.getenv("FOO") is not None:
    pass
```

I would like to know which method, if either, is a good/preferred conditional and why.

Comment: It is primarily opinion based. Both serve the same purpose. I will prefer method 1 as it is cleaner

Comment: I can't say there's anything in it. Pick one (flip a coin?) and reevaluate later if it turns out not to work. Frankly I think you've spent more time typing this question than you'd save either way!

Comment: Opinion based. I would use the first, but it's up to you.

Comment: so you want to check if a var is exist ?? right ??

Comment: @Ayoub: I think you forgot to see question *"What is a good practice to check if an **environmental variable exists** or not in Python?"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your comment. I asked this question in order to know the community's convention. As the Zen says: `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`. I wanted to know that *one* way here.

Comment: Opinion based. Method 1 syntax serves better, since you ask if `foo` is in the env vars, not if seeking for `foo` results in `None` values.

Comment: But that way might not be obvious, unless you're Dutch...

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Use the first; it directly tries to check if something is defined in `environ`. Though the second form works equally well, it's lacking semantically since you get a value back if it exists and *only* use it for a comparison.

You're trying to see if something is present *in* `environ`, why would you *get* just to compare it and then *toss it away*?

That's exactly what `getenv` does:

> *Get an environment variable*, return `None` if it doesn't exist. The
>   optional second argument can specify an alternate default.

(this also means your check could just be `if getenv("FOO")`)

you don't want to *get it*, you want to check for it's existence.

Either way, `getenv` is just a wrapper around `environ.get` but you don't see people checking for membership in mappings with:

```
from os import environ
if environ.get('Foo') is not None:
```

To summarize, use:

```
if "FOO" in os.environ:
    pass
```

if you *just* want to check for existence, while, use `getenv("FOO")` if you actually want to do something with the value you might get.

Comment: Conversely:  Why would you check it's present, if you're not going to use it? Perhaps he's only asking about the error-checking aspect, but later his program uses it. (This is very common). It would be most cohesive to capture the value at the same time the check is made. There is a less-likely case, that OP wants to check before calling a subprogram that needs it, but Occam's razor suggests this is the less likely case.

Comment: I did it like that:
`foo = os.environ.get("FOO");
if foo is not None:
    do_something(foo)`

Comment: @ThomasW My case is exactly your "less-likely" case, of needing to check whether the user has remembered to source a third party script before trying to build for Emscripten.  In fact, that's the first thing all our build scripts do for all platforms.

Answer (score 68):

There is a case for either solution, depending on what you want to do conditional on the existence of the environment variable.

## Case 1

When you want to take different actions purely based on the existence of the environment variable, without caring for its value, the first solution is the best practice. It succinctly describes what you test for: is 'FOO' in the list of environment variables.

```
if 'KITTEN_ALLERGY' in os.environ:
    buy_puppy()
else:
    buy_kitten()
```

## Case 2

When you want to set a default value if the value is not defined in the environment variables the second solution is actually useful, though not in the form you wrote it:

```
server = os.getenv('MY_CAT_STREAMS', 'youtube.com')
```

or perhaps

```
server = os.environ.get('MY_CAT_STREAMS', 'youtube.com')
```

Note that if you have several options for your application you might want to look into [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap), which allows to merge multiple dicts based on keys. There is an example of this in the `ChainMap` documentation:

```
[...]
combined = ChainMap(command_line_args, os.environ, defaults)
```

As pointed out by [@Levon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596068/4398595), this might return unexpected results if the variable is set but empty. You should therefore also check the returned value. For example like:

```
combined = ChainMap(command_line_args, os.environ)
server = combined.get("MY_CAT_STREAMS") or defaults["MY_CAT_STREAMS"]
```

Answer (score 33):

To be on the safe side use

```
os.getenv('FOO') or 'bar'
```

A corner case with the above answers is when the environment variable is set but is empty

For this special case you get

```
print(os.getenv('FOO', 'bar'))
# prints new line - though you expected `bar`
```

or

```
if "FOO" in os.environ:
    print("FOO is here")
# prints FOO is here - however its not
```

To avoid this just use **`or`**

```
os.getenv('FOO') or 'bar'
```

Then you get

```
print(os.getenv('FOO') or 'bar')
# bar
```

**When do we have empty environment variables?**

You forgot to set the value in the `.env` file

```
# .env
FOO=
```

or exported as

```
$ export FOO=
```

or forgot to set it in `settings.py`

```
# settings.py
os.environ['FOO'] = ''
```

---

**Update:** if in doubt, check out these one-liners

```
>>> import os; os.environ['FOO'] = ''; print(os.getenv('FOO', 'bar'))

$ FOO= python -c "import os; print(os.getenv('FOO', 'bar'))"
```

Comment: The signature for getenv is `def getenv(key, default=None):` so if so that should allow a default vs the or syntax at the start

Comment: @Chris McKee try this `>>> import os; os.environ['FOO'] = ''; print(os.getenv('FOO', 'bar'))`

Comment: Misleading method signature 

Comment: @Chris McKee, another example `$ FOO=  python -c "import os; print(os.getenv('FOO', 'bar'))"`

Answer (score 12):

In case you want to check if multiple env variables are not set, you can do the following:

```
import os

MANDATORY_ENV_VARS = ["FOO", "BAR"]

for var in MANDATORY_ENV_VARS:
    if var not in os.environ:
        raise EnvironmentError("Failed because {} is not set.".format(var))
```

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend the following solution.

It prints the env vars you didn't include, which lets you add them all at once. If you go for the for loop, you're going to have to rerun the program to see each missing var.

```python
from os import environ

REQUIRED_ENV_VARS = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
diff = REQUIRED_ENV_VARS.difference(environ)
if len(diff) > 0:
    raise EnvironmentError(f'Failed because {diff} are not set')
```

Comment: You don't need to check the length of the diff, just using `if diff:` does the trick (and perhaps change `diff` to `missing_variables` for a more descriptive name). Also in python 3.8 and up you could use the walrus operator to compress it some more: `if missing_variables := REQUIRED_ENV_VARS.difference(environ):`.

Comment: Neat trick! Note the var type `dict` instead of `list`.

Comment: @MarkHu It is actually a `set` type. `print(type({'a', 'b', 'c'}))` yields `<class 'set'>` as output.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you're using an environment variable named `Foo` which could change based on different environments, I would suggest to get its value and INFO (or DEBUG) log it even if you use its value (e.g. boolean) just as a toggle or decision-making criterion. It could help you when something goes wrong or just for sanity check later.

```
#python=3.8

import os
import logging

foo = os.getenv("FOO")

if foo:
    logging.info(f"Proceeding since environment variable FOO exists {foo=}")
    pass
else:
    # proper action/logging based on the context
    pass
```

I would advise against hardcoding alternatives in the code itself without proper logging. Using `foo = os.getenv("FOO", "BAR")` could silently change the behavior of your code.

Also, it is best to have all your constants either in a config file or as environment variables and don't hardcode anything in the source code itself. Defaults and alternatives could go inside the config file and environment-changing constants should be env vars so that you could change them during the deployments easily.