# Python key exist or not?

Tags: python

How to know key exists in Python?

Import the os module:

```
import os
```

To get an environment variable:

```
os.environ.get('Env_var')
```

To set an environment variable:

```
# Set environment variables
os.environ['Env_var'] = 'Some Value'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good practice to check if an environmental variable exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697845/what-is-a-good-practice-to-check-if-an-environmental-variable-exists-or-not)

Comment: The documentation for the *os* module will help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check If Key Exists using the Inbuilt method keys()

```
def checkKey(dic, key):
    if key in dic.keys():
        print("Present, ", end =" ")
        print("value =", dic[key])
    else:
        print("Not present")
         
# Driver Code
dic = {'a': 100, 'b':200, 'c':300}
key = 'b'
checkKey(dic, key)
 
key = 'w'
checkKey(dic, key)
```

```
Output:
Present, value = 200
Not present
```

Check If Key Exists using if and in

```
def checkKey(dic, key):
     
    if key in dic:
        print("Present, ", end =" ")
        print("value =", dic[key])
    else:
        print("Not present")
 
# Driver Code
dic = {'a': 100, 'b':200, 'c':300}
key = 'b'
checkKey(dic, key)
 
key = 'w'
checkKey(dic, key)
```

```
Output:
Present, value = 200
Not present
```

Check If Key Exists using has_key() method

```
def checkKey(dic, key):
     
    if dic.has_key(key):
        print("Present, value =", dic[key])
    else:
        print("Not present")
 
# Driver Function
dic = {'a': 100, 'b':200, 'c':300}
key = 'b'
checkKey(dic, key)
 
key = 'w'
checkKey(dic, key)
```

```
Output:
Present, value = 200
Not present
```

Check If Key Exists using get()

```
dic = {'a': 100, 'b':200, 'c':300}
 
# cheack if "b" is none or not.
if dic.get('b') == None:
  print("Not Present")
else:
  print("Present")
```

```
Output:
Present
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using if statement**: You can simply check using an if statement:

```
if os.getenv('Env_var') is not None:
    val = os.getenv('Env_var')
    print(f'Value is {val}')
else:
    print('Entry not found!')
```

**Using default value**: Alternatively, you can use the dictionary's `get` function to retrieve the value associated with the key or return a default value if the entry does not exist. This may be useful if you wish to assign a default value for processing.

```
val = os.getenv('Env_var', -1)

if val == -1:
    print('Entry not found!')
else:
    print(f'Value is {val}')
```